# No Output From LM2596-5T from TI. Any Ideas Why?

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck, switching-regulator

So I built a board with LM2596-5T as the voltage regulator. Below are my schematics.Just as described in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf).
[image]

And the layout is as below:
[image]

After assembling, the output is at 0V. Vpin12 is 24V (VIN=24V). But nothing on the output pin at all. I would have thought I should get at least 1.23V (VREF). Can anyone spot anything I might be getting wrong?

Here is my BoM:

1. C9: 680uF, 63V Electrolytic Cap.
2. U5: [LM2596-5T](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf)
3. D1: [SB530](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/SB/SB530.pdf)
4. L1: [33470C](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/281/kmp_3300-48725.pdf)
5. C12: 220uF, 25V Electrolytic Cap.

Comment: Can't tell you for sure since I haven't seen your physical board or poked around with probes, but it's likely your issue is something mechanical about the build or a soldering mistake. Something of that nature so do a thorough visual check and look for shorts, reversed components, and whatnot. You can also trace thru the circuit with a multimeter or scope.

Comment: I did check for shorts and open circuits. Thank you for response, though.

Comment: The culprit seemed to have been caught by the gentlemen who've answered.

Answer (score 6):

Your inductor is connected wrong. You should have wired it up to pins 1 and 3 (diagonally opposite):

[image: Inductor Wiring]

As a result the inductor is basically on open circuit, so you will get no output.

Given your VCC trace passes right next to pin 3, you should be able to simply scape off any soldermask from the trace where it passes the inductor pin, and make the connection with a blob of solder.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Confirming the inductor pinout is something I definitely overlooked.

Comment: If this worked for you, please "accept" this answer and give Tom his due credit.

Answer (score 3):

The data sheet for the inductor show the connections on pins 1 and 3, which are diagonally opposite.  You have them connected on one side of the inductor.